# Android set gravity of a textview dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, textview, gravity

I dynamically added horizontal layouts to my activity, and I am trying to put `textviews` inside of them.

The problem is, I can't manage to put some `textviews` To the right and some to the left.

I tried `textview.setgravity`, but it just changed the place of the text inside the `textview` instead of moving the `textview` itself.

Edit : here is some of my code to help you get an idea :

```
for(int i=0;i<nbelem;i++){          //génération des boutons des commandes
        layouts[i] = new RelativeLayout(this);
        layouts[i].setClickable(true);      //toute la zone est cliquable
        layouts[i].setId(i);
        layouts[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 150));


        Info[i] = new TextView(this);
        Info[i].setClickable(true); 
        Info[i].setId(i);
        Info[i].setText("Pizza 4 fromages x2 \n Pizza chevre x2");
        Info[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        layouts[i].addView(Info[i]);


        Numcom[i] = new TextView(this);
        Numcom[i].setClickable(true);
        Numcom[i].setId(i);
        Numcom[i].setText("n°1522");
        Numcom[i].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP);              
        Numcom[i].setTextSize(12);
        Numcom[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,50));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds that `RelativeLayout` may suit your needs and save you lots of nested `LinearLayout`s which are not recommended (performance wise).

Comment: the problem is, I want some textviews on the left,and other on the rught, therefir,I cannot change the gravity of the layout

Comment: add a sketch of the layout you want to achieve and I'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a layout gravity to the LinearLayout that contains your textview.

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
lp.gravity= Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
textview1.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Be sure that you use [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: i get a "lp.gravity cannot be resolved or is not a field"
i saw it on another question, and tried the solution they gave to him,but even with the package, it's still not reckonised.

Comment: I think your LayourPrms are type RelativeLayout and there fore you can use "tetxview.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT)" on the child.